# length () of string does not return true value

Tags: c++, string, size

I want to implement the decryption function using AES algorithm, the function takes two aguments: string encryptedstring and string key.
on the other hand in the AES algorithm the size of input string is matter but when i copy and paste the encrypted string the size of the string is not what i expect:
`decrypttest("(��P�$Y���k>","01 03 05 07 09 0A 0C 0E 02 04 06 08 0B 0D 0F 00");`
the size of `(��P�$Y���k>` should `16` but when i call `size()` or `length()` functions they return `28`,
the interesting thing is that when i put this string in the `file` and read it from the file the function `size()` returns true value which is `16`.
I do not know how can i solve this problem.

Comment: Don't try to copypaste binary data as text. If you want to do that, convert it to something like base64 first.

Comment: *but when i copy and paste* -- You should be using a hex editor, and not a text editor.  As a matter of fact, you should be using a hex editor anyway if the data is binary.  All of those crazy characters you posted is an indication you are assuming the data is text, when it isn't.

Comment: i dont use texteditor, when i call my encryption function the encrypted string is shown in the terminal, now i want to decrypt the encrypted string the only way is to copy the encrypted string and paste it as my argument for decryption function am i right? would you please tell me how can i do that in the right way? tanx

Comment: I'm guessing your file is encoded in utf-8, if you want exact binary bytes in a string use escape sequences, e.g. `"\xAF\xDE"

Comment: No my file is not UTF-8, the only thing that i want to know is how can i give (��P�$Y���k> which is the encrypted string as an argument to decryption function in the way that the size would be correct? tnx

Comment: OK, if your cpp file isn't encoded in utf-8 what encoding does it use? The same still applies regardless of the encoding, use byte literals to get specific bytes in a string when not using basic text characters

Answer (score 0):

used the output of encryption as input of decryption without copy-paste and worked. because string will delete some padding from the variable. and using hex is the solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).